# Data in tables after DROP DATABASE and recreate

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Just came into the 'feature' I had no idea will ever happen. We have two servers for development - `S1` and `S2`. We most often use S2 and S1 went out of date. Let's assume that `S1`'s database `DB1` stays at `C:\mssql\data\db1.mdf`

What I did:

1. Drop database `DB1` on `S1`
2. Scripted `DB1` on `S2` without data as `CREATE DATABASE...` and create tables, indexes, etc...
3. Run script on `S1`, to create new `DB1` as on `S2`.

although I didn't delete `db1.mdf` file, after dropping and recreating I expected my tables to have no data. What was my surprise after finding some tables filled!

What's the explanation for that?

Cheers.

Comment: 2008 and 2008R2 are different versions - which one do you use?

Comment: Does your `model` database contain any tables that contain data? If not I suspect the process is not exactly as you described.

Comment: @dezso - I use 2008R2

Comment: @MartinSmith - Before structure migration I have both databases populated, the process is as described

Comment: Did you check `model`? Apart from that if you dropped the database and recreated from scratch using TSQL scripts and are definitely connecting to the right server/DB the only way it can contain data is if something has inserted it. Either your scripts or maybe some other application.

Comment: Did you "create" the database using the `user instances = true` and `AttachDbFileName` settings in your connection string?

Comment: @AaronBertrand No, it was done through SSMS on a normal user-based connection. My `model` tables are empty.

Comment: Then the only possible explanation for extra tables being present in your database immediately after creation is that they are also in the `model` database.

Comment: It's not EXTRA tables, it's filled existing tables!

Comment: @makciook - Without access to your environment this is not going to be answerable. It's going to be some silly thing your end. Either your scripts do contain `INSERT` statements. Some application is connecting and inserting. You are looking at the wrong database. or something like that. SQL Server certainly isn't doing it on its own.